# How to properly integrate: $\int_0^1 f_i'(y) f_0'(y) dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

can someone tell me how to integrate:
$$\int_0^2  f_l'(y) f_0'(y) dy.$$

I know: $f_l (2)=f_l(0)=0$

I have tried:
$ \int_0^2 f_l' f_0'dy=\int_0^2 (f_l f_0' )' dy- \int_0^2 f_l f_0'' dy$

or:$ \int_0^2 f_l' f_0'dy=- \int_0^2 f_l f_0'' dy$

but this doesn't seem to help me...

Comment: There isn't enough information to solve the problem as given (consider that you could multiply $f_l$ by any constant, maintaining the boundary conditions but changing the value of the integral by that same constant factor).  Is this the precise problem you need to solve, or is there possibly additional information?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Supposing that: $f_0(2)=f_0(0)$. Can I then conclude that the integral is zero?

Comment: Consider your integration by parts; even with $f_0(0) = f_0(2) = 0$ you can have $f_0''(y)\lt 0$ for all $y\in[0,2]$ (for instance, if $f_0 = x(2-x)$ and have e.g. $f_l(y)\gt 0$ for all $y\in(0,2)$; then the same scaling-factor argument shows that these can actually be arbitrary values.  (In fact, even without doing the integration by parts explicitly you can just choose $f_0(x) = C_0x(2-x)$ and $f_l(x) = C_lx(2-x)$, where both functions are $0$ at the endpoints and the integral can easily be evaluated to be the arbitrary $\frac{32}3C_0C_l$.

Comment: What's more, even imposing restrictions like specifying the value of $\int_0^2f_0(y)dy$ won't be enough; your core conditions allow for arbitrary 'overlap' between $f_0$ and $f_l$.  Imagine doing piecewise definitions like $f_0(x) = 0$ for $x\in[0, \frac34)$ and $_0f(x)$ quadratic or even just 'smoothed' with $f_0(\frac34)=f_0(2) = 0$, with a mirrored piecewise definiton for $f_l$; then in the region $(\frac34, \frac54)$ you can get essentially arbitrary behavior.